# Will installing Windows 8 remove Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8

As of now I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7. I'm planing on upgrading  Windows 7 to Win8. After upgrading will Windows 8 delete my current installation of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Windows likes to be in the first partition because its fussy. You can partition your hard drive yourself with Gparted for example, install windows and reinstall the grub bootloader, but that’s messy and I would not be the best at explaining how that works unfortunately.

But to answer your question yes windows will attempt to overwrite Ubuntu.

*Edit*

Although if win7 is in the first partition it may not, sorry I didnt think about that in my first comment. I apologise. Do you have the win8 disc? if you do its no harm putting it in and testing, just don't agree to the format of course if it suggests it.